# Reading a CSV file in java and displaying contents

Tags: java

I want to create a program that will read a Comma Separated Value  file which will contain 
[employee name,company name,salary].
and displays output like 
Employee name:--,Salary:---,Company:--

For this, i have created 2 classes.i have just written a simple program which will read and display Comma Separated Value file. i want to know how can i display contents separately?

```
package com.readcsvfile;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadCsvFile { 

  private String currentLine;
  BufferedReader br; 
  public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException { 
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
  while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
  System.out.println(currentLine); 
  }
 }
}##
```

---

```
package com.readcsvfile.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.readcsvfile.ReadCsvFile;

public class ReadCsvFileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadCsvFile r1 = new ReadCsvFile();
    String fileName = "D://sample2.csv";

    try {
        r1.readFile(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }
 }

}


##
```

Comment: How can i attached my java files here?

Comment: You don't. You paste them in, indented 4 extra spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: post your codes in question only.

Comment: @supriya410 i have edited it

Comment: What exactly is your issue here?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReadCsvFile { 

    private String currentLine;
    BufferedReader br;

    public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException { 
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
         while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
           String [] lineAfterSplit = currentLine.split(",");
           System.out.print("Employee Name:--"+ lineAfterSplit[0] + " Company Name:--" + lineAfterSplit[1] + " Salary:--" + "lineAfterSplit[2]);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your br.readLine() reads the entire line in the input file. It is a CSV file, so you got to split the line by a comma. (currentLine.split(",") does that)

Comment: @supriya410 you can split string. Here your each lines contains comma seperated values, we can split that line using comma that will return an array of element.

Comment: But what if we are reading another file like text file and pdf?

Comment: if it is a text file, you read the entire line. You may use space as a delimiter but that isn't recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method to do something like this to split the input into the required output:

```
String[] str = currentLine.split(",");
System.out.println("Employee Name: " + str[0] + ",Salary: " + str[1] + ",Company:" + str[2]);
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class ReadCsvFile {
    private String currentLine;
    BufferedReader br; 
    public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException { 
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            String[] str = currentLine.split(",");
            System.out.println("Employee Name: " + str[0] + ",Salary: " + str[1] + ",Company:" + str[2]); 
        }
    }
}
```